# Are blocked and blocked/suspend processes put into the same queue?

Tags: process, scheduling, process-management

In a 7-state process model (new, ready, blocked, running, blocked/suspend, blocked/ready, exit), are processes in the blocked and blocked/suspend states for each event that processes are blocked on put into the same queue or are they seperate?

Answer (score 0):

Do you have a link for the particular 7-state process model?  Generally, blocked processes are put on queues belonging to the events they are waiting for, so the answer would be no.  Only the blocked/ready processes would be on a run queue (and even then, depending on the scheduler and number of cores there could be multiple run queues).